# Rubymine - Java runtime not found on mac os, but it's in the terminal

Tags: java, macos, rubymine

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.4, and I just installed java 1.7.

If I run java -version from command line, I get:

> java version "1.7.0_09"

But I'm trying to install RubyMine, and I get the following message:

> To open "RubyMine" you need a Java runtime. Would you like to install one now?

If I click Install when this message pops up then it complains and says

> The software is currently unavailable

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RubyMine requires Apple Java 1.6 to run, it will not work on JDK 1.7. You need to install Java 1.6 from Apple.

If install doesn't work, [check this](http://mattryall.net/blog/2011/08/manually-installing-java-on-os-x-lion).

Comment: Cheers!

I downloaded java 1.6 from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 and it works now :) 

I think my company does have an update server as well - so the other link probably solves the problem with java not being able to be downloaded automatically.